# Python vtkInterface0.9.3 library examples not working

Tags: python, vtk

I found out about `vtkInterface`, a python `vtk` wrapper that facilitates `vtk` plotting.

Trying to run their first example, under `Initialize from Numpy Arrays` in this page: [vtkInterface.PolyData](http://vtkinterface.readthedocs.io/en/latest/polydata.html), by simply running the code as is, and it results in a gray render window with nothing in it.
Some of the other examples do work but this is exactly the thing that I need at the moment and was wondering if anybody has tried it and knows what might be wrong.

Example Code:

```
import numpy as np
import vtkInterface

# mesh points
vertices = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                     [1, 0, 0],
                     [1, 1, 0],
                     [0, 1, 0]])

# mesh faces
faces = np.hstack([[4, 0, 1, 2, 3],  # square
                   [3, 0, 1, 4],     # triangle
                   [3, 1, 2, 4]])    # triangle

surf = vtkInterface.PolyData(vertices, faces)

# plot each face with a different color
surf.Plot(scalars=np.arange(3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is wrong. It lacks a fifth point. For example this will work.

```
vertices = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                    [1, 0, 0],
                    [1, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0],
                    [0.5, 0.5, -1]])
```

Explanation: In VTK, faces are encoded in the following way:

```
face_j = [ n, i_0, i_1, ..., i_n ]
```

Here, `n` is the number of points per face, and `i_k` are the indices of the points in the vertex-array. The face is formed by connecting the points `vertices[i_k]` with `k in range(0,n)`. A list of faces is created by simply concatenating the single face specifications:

```
np.hstack([face_0, face_1, ..., face_j, ...])
```

The advantage of this encoding is that the number of points used per face, `n`, can vary. So a mesh can consist of lines, triangles, quads, etc.

In the example, the vertex with id 4 is used in the second and third face. So `vertices` is required to consist of at least five entries. Surprisingly, the sample doesn't crash, as VTK almost certainly would if some faces were accessing non-existing points.

Comment: Maintainer of vtkInterface here.  Thanks for catching this, and I've updated the documentation.  Update will be up in the next version 0.11.1